# React: pushing an updated object to an array when index is dynamic and changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this layout below that if you click on any Tiles under each Category, it should push that tile to the dashboard on the right while also removing that tile from the sidebar. After I clicked on Tile 0 for example, it got removed from the sidebar and got added to Category 3 under Tile 0 on the right hand side dashboard.

My current dashboard state has this shape after the first add tile click:

```
[
   0: {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Category 3',
      tiles: [
         0: {
            category: 'Category 3',
            id: 'tile0',
            name: 'Tile 0'
         },
      ]
   }
]
```

The problem comes when I try to add the second tile of Categories that are not in order (Adding tiles from Category 2 first for example) Here is a portion my code:

```
const handleAddTiles = (categoryName, categoryIndex) {
    
    tiles.forEach(tile => {

       const categoryExists = dashboardState.map(category => 
       category.name).includes(tile.category)

       if (categoryExistOnDashboard) {
          setDashboardState((prevState) => {
             const categories = [...prevState];
             const categoryToUpdate = { ...categories[categoryIndex] }; // prints the state above
             const categoryTiles = [...categoryToUpdate.tiles, tile ]; // adds a new tile
             categoryToUpdate.tiles = categoryTiles; // replace previous tiles with new tiles

             // categories[categoryIndex] below is faulty indexing logic
             categories[categoryIndex] = { ...categoryToUpdate };

             return [...categories]; // set the state to our new copy
       }) 
       }
    })  
}
```

The above code works by grabbing the Category index from the sidebar when I click on the tiles, and it only works if I add down the list in order due to indexing. The problem is now if I decide to add tiles from Category 2 first for example, the categoryIndex would be 2 but on the dashboard it's index would be 0 since it's the only Category on there. So the categoryToUpdate would be undefined since it can't find index 2 on the dashboard. I can't think of a way to correctly grab the right object from the dashboard state in order to update my state to save my life. I thought about using categoryName to match my item but no idea how to use that to replace categories[categoryIndex].

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I think what you need is find category based on id so may be categories.find where you would match id  with categories to update and not index if that makes sense
if a categoryToUpdate id exists update that or add new one

Comment: @Anuj So similar idea to categoryName, but how would I replace categories[categoryIndex] with that id to set state?

Comment: I think you can use findIndex on categories, const index = categories.finIndex(category => category.id === categoryToUpdate.id) now if it finds the index it will return the index if it does not it returns -1 so you can put a check on index > 0 and then do category[index] , if it's not found you can use .concat or whatever you prefer to append new category,  but updating this way you will still be mutating your categories array which should be okay as long as you know what you are replacing

Comment: and a second approach would be to do a find on category categories.find(category => category.id === categoryToUpdate.id) and if the element was found 
you can do a map on categories like categories.map(category => if (category.id === foundElement or categoryToUpdate.id) you return a new object else you just return the category as is, if find returns undefined then no need to map you can simply append your new category, both findIndex/find are based on unique ids cause these methods will return 1st matching element so as long as you have unique ids you can use either. find/map will be cleaner

Comment: @Anuj findIndex is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: glad I could be of some help !